# Assign PHP value to MovableType var

Tags: php, movabletype

Is there any way to assign a PHP value (like some $_REQUEST data) to MovableType, for example, as the *offset* or *lastn* attributes of *mt:Entries* loop?

Comment: Is it safe to assume you're using dynamic publishing? Remember, in static publishing, the MT variables are rendered before the server (and therefore PHP) would have anything to do with the content.

Comment: If I put dynamic publishing, the page returns a 404

Comment: So it sounds like you were trying to use static publishing, correct? For dynamic, if memory serves there was some other template that was also required, but I don't remember what -- a 404 would indicate you haven't done that. Perhaps describing your goal would be the best place to start.